# CSS Button Multiline in paragraph like an anchor tag (IE11 also)

Tags: html, css

#### EDIT: @Dinesh karthik solution work well but sadly not on IE11. I try to make it work also in IE11

How to display a button like an anchor tag in a paragraphe.

I mean allow a button to have a line break and have the same behaviour than an anchor tag

```css
button{
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-stretch: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    letter-spacing: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    white-space: normal;
}
.demo{
  width: 150px;
  background: #ccc;
}

a, button{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<h3>With a button</h3>
<p class="demo">
Hello world <button>find more information here</button> and keep calm
</p>

<h3>With an anchor</h3>
<p class="demo">
Hello world <a>find more information here</a> and keep calm
</p>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/zecka/pen/dyObwMm

Answer (score 1):

change display css in button from `display:inherit` to  `display:contents`

```css
button{
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: contents;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-stretch: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    letter-spacing: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    white-space: normal;
}
.demo{
  width: 150px;
  background: #ccc;
}

a, button{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<h3>With a button</h3>
<p class="demo">
Hello world <button>find more information here</button> and keep calm
</p>

<h3>With an anchor</h3>
<p class="demo">
Hello world <a>find more information here</a> and keep calm
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, good solution but seems not compatible with IE11 :/

Comment: Try with @support css bro

Comment: @support is only to check if browser support the property, right ? I try to make it work also in IE11. But your solution is already a good entry point :)

Comment: I am not well with @support css just suggesting to try bro and if you find the css for ie11 please add to the answer in comment bro it also be a help me when i doing this type of css bro and thank you for support

Answer (score 0):

`display: contents` has accessibility issues (buttons won't focus correctly). There is no other way (currently) to accomplish what you're asking, since buttons **cannot be inline**.

I recommend just using `<div>` elements with `role="button"`. See https://benfrain.com/converting-divs-into-accessible-pseudo-buttons/ for an example of how to do this.